# would like create a class where variables are available to other classes

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "people.h"
#include "birthday.h"
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string myname;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;


    std::cout << " What is your name " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, myname);
    std::cout << "What month where you born " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "What day where you born " <<  std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "What year where you born in " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;
    birthday birthdayobjects(a ,b ,c);
    people peopleobjects(myname, birthdayobjects);
    peopleobjects.printInfo();
}
```

I have my main.cpp file like this where I have two constructors that take parameters, that are input by the user. I would like to condense this down to a single function so the main file looks something like this.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "people.h"
    #include "birthday.h"
    #include <string>
    #include "askquestions.h"

int main(){
    askquestions getquestions();
    birthday birthdayobjects(a ,b ,c);
    people peopleobjects(myname, birthdayobjects);
    peopleobjects.printInfo();
}
```

but the issue is when I try this the variables are not seen in that scope. If I put the variables in the ask-questions class, then the classes in the main function that rely on the input do not get the parameters. I tried extern but it compiled but did not work properly. When I try to make the variables global in the main.cpp file that also doesn't work. What is the best option in this case?

Comment: This is going to sound funny, but `askquestions getquestions();` is a function declaration, not a variable definition. Use `askquestions getquestions;` or `askquestions getquestions{};` instead.

Comment: it was a typo , its suppose to be object for the askquestion class

Answer (score 0):

First point

```
askquestions getquestions();
```

is wrong (it declares a function called `getquestions` not a variable), it should be

```
askquestions getquestions;
```

Design your `askquestions` class like this

```
class askquestions
{
public:
     askquestions();
     int geta() { return a; }
     int getb() { return b; }
     int getc() { return c; }
private:
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
};
```

The three `getX` methods are called *getters* and are a typical way that you get information out of a class.

Then in your main function use the getters like this

```
int main()
{
    askquestions getquestions;
    birthday birthdayobjects(getquestions.geta(), getquestions.getb(), getquestions.getc());
    ...
}
```

See how the getter methods are called using the `getquestions` variable you've previously declared.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for `askquestions` to be a class. For this you should prefer a free function that returns a `birthday`, or better a `people`

For example

```
people askquestions()
{
    std::string myname;
    int month; // prefer descriptive names to single letters unless the single letter 
               // has a widely recognized meaning in the algorithm
    int day;
    int year;

    std::cout << " What is your name " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, myname);
    std::cout << "What month where you born " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> month;
    std::cout << "What day where you born " <<  std::endl;
    std::cin >> day;
    std::cout << "What year where you born in " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> year;

    return people(myname, birthday (month ,day , year));
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(){
    people peopleobjects = getquestions();
    peopleobjects.printInfo();
}
```